# Form to email not working for hotmail

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I've got a simple form to email PHP system that works just fine for me, because my webmail comes from One and they support server side email scripts. But the problem is that Hotmail does not, so my form doesn't work for emails that don't support what One does support. I've looked through the internet to find the perfect solution, but PHP is not something that I like to use so playing around with it is not my cup of tea. Incase you wonder what my PHP mail folder currently looks like, have a look:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$workshop = $_POST['workshop'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$information = $_POST['information'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];


if( !isset($_POST['name'])) { die("No Direct Access"); } 

    $spam = $_POST['username'];

    if($spam) {  
        die("error: Spam"); 
        } else {

        }


$formcontent=" Naam: $name \n\n Achternaam: $lastname \n\n Email: $email \n\n Telefoon: $phone \n\n Workshop: $workshop \n\n Locatie: $location \n\n Contacten via: $contact \n\n Extra informatie: $information";
$recipient = "Something@Something.com";
$subject = "Workshop klant";
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header('Location: verzonden.html');
```

As you can see, this is very basic stuff. That's why I came to the place where people know much much more about this than me.

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: By spoofing the "from" email address you're basically no different than a spammer to all email providers. This is why all major companies send email from a standard sending only account like "noreply@...". You will need to setup a real email account to send from if you want major providers to accept your email.

Comment: I typically use something like Amazon SES or Sendgrid for this sort of thing and it works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not intending this to endorse Mailgun over other solutions. This is just what I have code handy to illustrate. Sending mail is no trivial thing with all of the spam and malware issues the world is plagued with. Mail will get blocked by major providers at the first hint of anything sketchy. If you need to send mail from a website, you should create an account somewhere to specifically send your mail from. Do a web search for "Bulk Mail Send" to see more options. Many are free for light use... Some are free for even fairly significant use.

If using Mailgun, you download their PHP to a folder in your webserver. Then have something like this:

In a config file somewhere:

```
// Mailgun connection info.
$GLOBALS['MAILGUN_API_KEY'] = '<your key from MailGun>';
$GLOBALS['MAILGUN_MAIL_DOMAIN'] = '<Your Domain>';
```

And a function to send mail:

```
<?php
require './mailgun-php/vendor/autoload.php';   
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
function mailgunSend($mailFrom, $mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailText, $mailHTML = null, $mailCC = null, $mailBCC = null, $mailAttachmentsArray = null) {
  $sendArray['from'] = $mailFrom;
  $sendArray['to'] = $mailTo;
  $sendArray['subject'] = $mailSubject;
  $sendArray['text'] = $mailText;
  if ($mailHTML != null) {
    $sendArray['html'] = $mailHTML;
  }
  if ($mailCC != null) {
    $sendArray['cc'] = $mailCC;
  }
  if ($mailBCC != null) {
    $sendArray['bcc'] = $mailBCC;
  }
  if ($mailAttachmentsArray != null) {
    $sendArray['attachment'] = $mailAttachmentsArray;
  }
  $mg = new Mailgun($GLOBALS['MAILGUN_API_KEY']);
  $mg->sendMessage($GLOBALS['MAILGUN_MAIL_DOMAIN'], $sendArray);
}
```

Finally, sending email with something like:

```
mailgunSend($GLOBALS['VERIFICATION_EMAIL_FROM'], $_SESSION["userEmail"], 
$GLOBALS['VERIFICATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT'], $mailBodyText, $mailBodyHTML);
```

You would of course need to compose your form data into the mail body. Hope that helps.